# What is python regex for removing all text in a column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean a column:

```
df:
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|     | league           | home_team          | away_team          | home_score   | away_score   |
+=====+==================+====================+====================+==============+==============+
|   0 | Champions League | APOEL              | Qarabag            | 1            | 2            |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|   1 | Champions League | FC Copenhagen      | TNS                | 1            | 0            |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|   2 | Champions League | AIK                | Maribor            | 3            | 2 ET         |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**expected**

```
df:
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|     | league           | home_team          | away_team          | home_score   | away_score   |
+=====+==================+====================+====================+==============+==============+
|   0 | Champions League | APOEL              | Qarabag            | 1            | 2            |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|   1 | Champions League | FC Copenhagen      | TNS                | 1            | 0            |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|   2 | Champions League | AIK                | Maribor            | 3            | 2            |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I am trying

```
df['away_score'] = df['away_score'].astype(str).str.replace('(\s?\w+)$', '', regex=True)
```

(works on regex101 but not in pandas)

But all the data in column is being replaced.

```
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|     | league           | home_team          | away_team          | home_score   | away_score   |
+=====+==================+====================+====================+==============+==============+
|   0 | Champions League | APOEL              | Qarabag            | 1            |              |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|   1 | Champions League | FC Copenhagen      | TNS                | 1            |              |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
|   2 | Champions League | AIK                | Maribor            | 3            | 2            |
+-----+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

What should be the correct regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clean up the text completely (including space), you should use:

```
df['away_score'] = df['away_score'].astype(str).str.replace('[a-zA-Z\s]', '', regex=True)
```

This way, you can also clean up the spaces before the alphabets, e.g. the space before `ET` in  `ET`.

If you want to clean up not only text but also some non-digit including symbols (leaving only digits), you can use:

```
df['away_score'] = df['away_score'].astype(str).str.replace('\D', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this regex, and it worked.

```
df['away_score'] = df['away_score'].astype(str).str.replace('[a-zA-Z]', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: I dunno why I am getting downvoted?! Any help how I can ask questions?

Comment: Your solution leaves some spaces there, you can use `df.to_dict()` to check it.  See my alternatively way to clean it completely below.